# Как правильно подключать .cpp модули?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть файл `core.cpp` с некоторыми функциями. Как правильно подключить `core.cpp` к моему проекту? Кроме того, и в `core.cpp`, и в главном модуле проекта, содержится директива `#include <windows.h>`. Не приведёт ли это к конфликту при покдлючении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что означает «подключить файл к проекту»? Исходя из `windows.h`, вы пользуетесь MSVC, так что просто добавьте файл в проект через правый клик -> Add existing item. Файл скомпилируется с проектом.

Если вы хотите пользоваться *функциями* из `core.cpp`, вам необходимо описание этих функций в header'е. Вам придётся либо раздобыть `core.h` там же, где вы взяли `core.cpp`, либо написать его самому.

Конфликта инклюдов не будет. Правильно написанный header можно включать сколько угодно раз как в одном файле, так и (тем более) в разных.